# How to make a stack navigator cover entire screen using React Navigation

Tags: react-native, expo, react-navigation

I am building a React Native project with Expo. For navigation, I am using react-navigation 6.0 with the following code for my main component:

```
export default class App extends Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <NavigationContainer>
        <Stack.Navigator initialRouteName={'SignIn'}  screenOptions={{
          headerShown: false
        }}>
          <Stack.Screen name="SignIn" component={SigninScr} />
          <Stack.Screen name="SignUp" component={SignupScr} />
          <Stack.Screen name="EmailVerification" component={EmailVerificationScr} />
        </Stack.Navigator>
    </NavigationContainer>
    );
  }
}
```

This works fine, but I haven't been able to make Stack.Navigator cover the entire screen. There is a weird area that's not covered by the Stack.Navigator:

[image]

I was reading through some of the [documentation](https://reactnavigation.org/docs/stack-navigator/) about stack navigator, but couldn't find any props or styling to force it to cover 100% of the screen. Does anyone know how to accomplish this?

Comment: Hi, are you sure it's not related to your screen signin ?

Comment: You can use background colors and borders to see, which components cover what area.